# .htaccess - How to remove part of url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, short

I tried almost everything but I have done something wrong. I want to change my url from:

http://website.com/component/products/product1?Itemid=101

to

http://website.com/product1

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^component/easydiscuss/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Please help
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a different product link as well, please? I'm not quite sure what that Itemid=101 doing there at the end.

Comment: Other products urls looks similarly:
http://website.com/component/products/product2?Itemid=101

If I manually remove ?Itemid=101 url still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file (place this code in the beginning):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^component/products/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

You can check your .htaccess file on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

This code does what you request: rewriting http://website.com/component/products/product1?Itemid=101 to http://website.com/product1.

If this is not working, please explain what is working and what is not. Also, test if http://website.com/product1 is working

Comment: I removed "0" and placed your code on the right place but nothing has changed.

Comment: Yes I removed the comma. You can see my current htaccess in the first post.

Comment: Corrected. Now its ok.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and explain a little bit more what is working and what is not? What messages do you get?